# Client side template library for mootools?

Tags: javascript, mootools, templating

I am using mootools for my project. Any recommendations for client side template library that plays well with mootools?

Comment: Just in case you didn't look there: http://mootools.net/forge/browse?search=template

Comment: Also check the documentation for String.substitute().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried mustache.js and it just worked fine. So I just decided to stick with it. 
@digitaraid Thanks for tips. Ones which are on forge appeared somewhat complex to me.

There is also [handlebars.js](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js) which is interesting too. I will try that in next few days.

Comment: I use mustache with MooTools just fine.  Good choice.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time MooTools `String.substitute()` works fine.

Another great script from Thomas Aylott is https://github.com/subtleGradient/mootools-subtle-templates . The repository seems dated, but the code is mostly basic JavaScript and works with the current MooTools version.

And of course, as mentioned, you can find more here: http://mootools.net/forge/browse?search=template .

Answer (score 0):

check out [JavaScript Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) by John Resig.
It's a tiny, yet powerful stand-alone script that offers a great templating solution.